# How to view all the users that have signed up for a certain website in django?

Tags: django

I am using django-auth , thus all the usernames are stored there . How do I retrieve all these users in a different app , to apply certain privileges to it ? Like databrowse admin , is there any way to browse the users (usernames) too ?

Comment: Every time I read one of your questions I obtain more and more proof that you don't read documentation.

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to view all the users that have registered without using the django-admin view .

Comment: Agreed, @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - but on the other hand, it seems to have paid off. I was wondering how he had twice the rep I do, then I saw he's posted *238* questions!. So *that's* how it's done - excuse me while I post a couple hundred more questions... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know how to do a query in Django, you shouldn't be trying to get django-auth working, or trying to change privileges or use the admin. Walk before you can run.

If you had a model (i.e. a table in the database) representing People:

```
class Person(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

how would you go about getting all of the people in your database? You'd use:

```
all_people = Person.objects.all()
```

to get a person with a particular name? Try:

```
joe = Person.objects.get(name__exact="joe")
```

so on. It's the same for django-auth's users.

```
from django.auth.models import User
users = User.objects.all()
for user in users:
    print user.username
```

Forget about applying privileges to anything. Concentrate on learning the absolute basics of Django, Querying and the ORM before you do anything else.

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/